# Ionic2 with no native plugins

Tags: cordova, typescript, plugins, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to use a non native audio plugin, because this is the only one I found that measures the DB while recording.

Plugin: https://github.com/remoorejr/cordova-plugin-media-with-compression

The thing is, that I'm pretty sure that I need to import the plugin into the .ts file, but I don't know how. The plugin is already installed.

Any clue how to use this plugin with Ionic2??

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Though never used this particular plugin.
Install it by

```
ionic plugin install cordova-plugin-media-with-compression --save
```

`save` should add an entry in `config.xml`.

Its global object seems to be [window.Media](https://github.com/remoorejr/cordova-plugin-media-with-compression/blob/master/plugin.xml#L44).

So in your **component** , do:

```
//import statements
    declare var window:any;
@Component({..})
```

And call the plugin functions within `platform.ready().then`

```
this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
   window.Media.fun()
})
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. I tried what you said, but still says that Media does not exist on type Window.  this.newFile = new this.window.Media(this.src...... But doesn't work. It says that cannot read property Media of undefined.

Comment: I did both, but still the same :(
I also tried with the MediaPlugin which is "Native" in Ionic2, but i get an error with getCurrentAmplitude(). Everything is wrong!! :(

Comment: Well I guess you could try raising an issue at the github link you posted.. This is the general way of integrating plugins

Comment: Sure! jeje. I'm using my device.